# How can I draw text on a path in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Is there a way to write text on a custom path with jetpack compose right now?**

Here is an example image of what I want to achieve:

[image: Text drawn on a half-circle path]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We use `nativeCanvas` to draw a text using `Path` in Compose, like how we do normally in Custom Views.

Ex:

```
@Composable
fun ArcTextExample() {
    val paint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint()
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        paint.apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            textSize = 24f
            typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        }

        drawIntoCanvas {
            val path = Path()
            path.addArc(RectF(0f, 100f, 200f, 300f), 270f, 180f)
            it.nativeCanvas.drawTextOnPath("Hello World Example", path, 0f, 0f, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

Note:
we should use `android.graphics.Path`

And the result will be like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! This definitely helps me a lot. I would be interested in a solution without `android.graphics` with just jetpack compose. Do you know if that's possible to do with just jetpack compose?

Comment: @fraherm, As per my understanding there is no method in`DrawScope` to draw text.

Comment: More recent versions of compose now have a draw text function: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview#common-drawing

Comment: @mipa As of this comment still not seeing any Compose options to draw text on a path.

Comment: Is there a way to repeat the text until possible.. example: make a full circle with the text "Hello World Example" so that you redraw the text until full 360 is covered..?