# Do I need set isAntiAlias when I use Android Compose Canvas?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717814/how-can-i-draw-text-on-a-path-in-jetpack-compose).

I know that maybe I need to set `isAntiAlias=true` when I use `nativeCanvas` just like Code A.

Do I need set `isAntiAlias` when I use Android Compose Canvas such as Code B ? If so, how can I do it?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ArcTextExample() {
    val paint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint()
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        paint.apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            textSize = 24f
            typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        }

        drawIntoCanvas {
            val path = Path()
            path.addArc(RectF(0f, 100f, 200f, 300f), 270f, 180f)
            it.nativeCanvas.drawTextOnPath("Hello World Example", path, 0f, 0f, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun setCanvas() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height

        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = canvasHeight),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = 0f),
            color = Color.Blue
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `isAntiAlias` is used when drawing text to the canvas, Because it will smoothen the edges

You have to access the native canvas from the Android framework in order to draw some text, you can call all the methods related to the native Canvas like `drawText()` or `drawVertices()`

To apply a style to the text, a Paint object must be used, and we can change `isAntiAlias` property just like the code A.

And in `compose` there is no concept of `Paint` because compose already took care of those and made easy to draw shapes, but for drawing texts you can only do this with help of `nativeCanvas` and `paint` where you can declare `AntiAlias_Flag` to true for smoothening the edges.